# I get errors to setup ReactJs Environment

Tags: reactjs

I am a react beginner to start learning.

Please check [this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_environment_setup.htm), it is a ReactJs environment setup tutorial. I just followed it, and on the last step when I start the server, I'm getting the following errors:

[image]

This is my `package.json`

{
  "name": "pacakge",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "webpack": "^2.5.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
  }
}

And this is my `webpack.config.js`

```js
var config = {
entry: './main.js',

output: {
   path:'./',
  filename: 'index.js',
},

devServer: {
  inline: true,
  port: 8080
},

module: {
  loaders: [
     {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',

        query: {
           presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      }
   ]
 }
}

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: While unrelated, I recommend you to use Create React App for learning. It has a recommended setup that works out of the box with no configuration, and you won't bump into issues like this.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```js
output: {
  path:'./',
  filename: 'index.js',
},
```

with:

```js
output: {
  path: __dirname + '/',
  filename: 'index.js',
},
```

or better:

```js
path = require('path')
...

output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, '/'),
  filename: 'index.js',
},
```

Comment: Hello, oklas, So much thank you for your advice.
I have changed the path as you recommended, but I can get the other errors now.

Comment: Ok. This mean current problem is solved. And need to describe next problem. Mark question as solved and make vote. And create another question where describe another problem and what you have try to do to solve of course. You may add link to another question here in comment.